# PayPal - Send secondary email confirmation though pay now form (not account)

Tags: paypal

I've been looking for a solution to this issue but can't quite find the correct one, here is the problem:

I'm working on a simple paypal integration tool, all it does is show a pay now form customized to each of our customers' payPayl account, when an end user pays our customer gets the payment (so far this works).

The problem is that I need it to also send a copy of the confirmation to our email address as well, but only for the transactions that go through this form, as customers will have other transactions from elsewhere that we shouldn't be getting confirmations for (so adding our company email to every customer's paypal account is not an option).

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be achieved? Is there a hidden field I can add which will do the trick? Here is a sample form:

```
Amount: {{this.amount}}
Paypal Email: {{this.paypalEmail}}
<br><br>
{{#if this.paypalEmail}}
    {{#if this.amount}}
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 30px; width: 200px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{this.paypalEmail}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Service Charge">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
            <table>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Service Charge">
                <strong>Invoice Amount: </strong><br>
                <h3>{{this.amount}}</h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{this.amount}}">
                <button style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color:mediumaquamarine; color: white; border-radius: 3px; border: 0px;" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay Now">Pay Now</button>
                <!--<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">-->
                <!--<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">-->
            </table>
        </form>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as we are stuck at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have not found an answer, but I did find an alternative, you can post a copy of the reply to an API by adding a hidden input field to the form, which is the next best thing I guess, from there you can email a copy or just process the results, here is the code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<API URL>">
```

I hope this helps anyone having this issue, it's was very frustrating.